# awk counting average for each minute in file

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, mean

Lets suppose I have a file like this:

> 13.03.2013 12:13:01|STRING1|NUMBER1|1|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:13:08|STRING1|NUMBER1|12|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:13:09|STRING3|NUMBER1|13|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:13:12|STRING2|NUMBER1|21|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:13:15|STRING2|NUMBER1|11|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:13:18|STRING1|NUMBER1|13|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:13:20|STRING2|NUMBER1|21|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:13:25|STRING3|NUMBER1|51|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:13:38|STRING2|NUMBER1|71|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:13:40|STRING1|NUMBER1|21|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:13:42|STRING1|NUMBER1|11|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:13:55|STRING3|NUMBER1|71|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:14:02|STRING1|NUMBER1|11|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:14:07|STRING1|NUMBER1|13|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:14:08|STRING3|NUMBER1|13|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:14:15|STRING2|NUMBER1|21|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:14:16|STRING2|NUMBER1|11|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:14:16|STRING1|NUMBER1|1|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:14:20|STRING2|NUMBER1|21|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:14:25|STRING3|NUMBER1|51|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:14:37|STRING2|NUMBER1|71|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:14:42|STRING1|NUMBER1|1|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:14:45|STRING1|NUMBER1|11|NUMBER3
>  
>   13.03.2013 12:14:58|STRING3|NUMBER1|51|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:15:06|STRING2|NUMBER1|11|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:15:13|STRING1|NUMBER1|43|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:15:22|STRING2|NUMBER1|21|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:15:26|STRING3|NUMBER1|51|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:15:35|STRING2|NUMBER1|71|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:15:40|STRING1|NUMBER1|1|NUMBER3
>   13.03.2013 12:15:42|STRING1|NUMBER1|21|NUMBER3
>  
>   13.03.2013 12:15:53|STRING3|NUMBER1|71|NUMBER3

I would like to find average for columns no 4 (after third `|`) for every minute only for variable `X`. For example, if `$X="STRING1"` the result should be:

> 13.03.2013 12:13|STRING1|11.6
>   13.03.2013 12:14|STRING1|7.4
>   13.03.2013 12:15|STRING1|21.666

So, we are looking in every minute lines with variable `$X` and calculate mean of those lines. How to deal with it ?

Comment: No, I'm writing script to analyse logs from one application. This is one of the steps.. I have stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following awk program:

*example.awk*:

```
$0 ~ SEARCH {
  split($1,time,":")
  min=time[2]
  total[min]+=$4
  count[min]++
  ts[min]=time[1]":"time[2]
}

END{
  for(m in total){
    printf "%s|%s|%s\n", ts[m],SEARCH,total[m]/count[m]
  }
}
```

Execute it:

```
awk -F'|' -v SEARCH=STRING1 -f example.awk your.log
```

Output:

```
13.03.2013 12:13|STRING1|11.6
13.03.2013 12:14|STRING1|7.4
13.03.2013 12:15|STRING1|21.6667
```

Comment: The order of output is not guaranteed. May need to sort on the time column

Comment: The order doesn't matter in my solution

Comment: But it might matter to the OP

Comment: You mean the order of the lines in output? Lines in input are likely ordered by time as it is a log file. Having this, the output will be sorted too (with zero effort). Am I missing something?

Comment: <strike>You are: in the END block you are iterating over the indices of an associative array. There is **no inherent order** in that loop.</strike> You are not: I was missing the fact that your array indices are integers. Nevermind.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v X="STRING1" '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" }
    $2 != X {next} 
    {min = substr($1,1,16)} 
    min != prev {
        if (NR>1) print prev, X, total/n
        total = n = 0
        prev = min
    } 
    {n++; total += $4} 
    END {print prev, X, total/n}
' file
```